# Computing an Expression

Tags: floating-point, numerical-algorithms, numerical-analysis

I am writing code to evaluate the following expression:
    $$ \frac{(a+b+c)!}{a! b! c!} $$
where $a$, $b$ and $c$ are on the range of $10$ to $500$. The result is going
to be a floating point number. I could use a big number package, but the code
will run slowly. I am using 64-bit floating point numbers.

I claim by doing as much of the computation in integer (maybe 64 bit) I will minimize the floating point round off error. Therefore, I claim that if put the integers to be multiplied together in an array, cancel common denominators, and then do the final computation in floating point I will minimize round off error.

Do I have this right?

Comment: "but the code will run slowly" How fast do you need? You might be surprised.

Comment: But you shouldn't worry about floating point errors, they're plenty accurate. Rather worry about overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use integers for any data. Just find the largest of three numbers `x=max(a,b,c)` and reduce both parts by `x!`. Then compute in doubles. For numbers as small as 500 both 32-bit ints and 32/64 bit doubles will be precise.

EDIT: Since 64-bit FP isn't enough to deal with `1500!`, you can perform computations on (decimal) logarithms of multipliers.

Comment: @Bulat I am thinking your solution will have more round off error than my solution. Please comment.

Comment: @Apass.Jack The idea is to do the cancellation of common factors with integer arithmetic and then do the final multiplies and divides in floating point.

Comment: @Apass.Jack I said "For numbers as small as 500 both 32-bit ints..."

Comment: @Bob All that I said is that your solution doesn't have any use of 64-bit integers. Source numbers are easily fit in 32-bit ints, and multiplications should be done in FP64 anyway.